# Showing a Colour Swatch in a Table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page that lets a user use the jquery minicolor widget to select a colour.  Another page lists the colours, and I liked the look of the swatch inside the minicolor widget.

Struggle as I might, I cannot seem to get a simple rectangle to show a sample of the colour in the data table.  I was thinking I could use their swatch by just copying it out, but it appears to depend upon the form and input.  All I see is a 2x2 pixel dot similar to this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Kieveli/5t2u0euy/2/

How do I get a nice rectangle swatch to display in a data table similar to how minicolour shows up?

```js
// Hide all stuffs
$('.rw_widget_colour').addClass('rw_hidden');

// Init minicolors
$('.text').minicolors();

// Set color
$('.colorpicker').minicolors('value', '#2ed1c1');

// Show
$('.rw_widget_colour').removeClass('rw_hidden');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.css">
<script src="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.js"></script>    


<form class="aui">
  <label class="rw_widget_colour">
    <div class="rw_widget_swatch">jaoja</div>
    <input class="text colorpicker" type="text" name="rw_widget_colour" value="#ff0"/>
  </label>
</form>

<!-- Show a swatch: -->

<table>
  <tr><td>
    <span class="minicolors-swatch minicolors-sprite minicolors-input-swatch">
      <span style="background-color: rgb(46, 209, 193);" class="minicolors-swatch-color"></span>
    </span>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you maybe create a screenshot of your desired effect/behavior? What should happen?

Comment: With 8K+ rep you should definitely know by now that your code goes in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the question but I put together an answer based on what I think you are looking for.

Basically, when the colour picker changes value (colour), we grab the newly selected background colour of the generated `span` and set it as the attribute for a table cell `td`.

You could easily modify it to adjust to your needs or add more details to your question clarifying the bits I misunderstood.

**UPDATED**

Based on comments, I am also displaying the colour code next to the colour sample (now contained within a `div` - adjust the sizes to your liking)

```js
$(function() {
  // Hide all stuffs
  $('.rw_widget_colour').addClass('rw_hidden');

  // Init minicolors
  $('.text').minicolors();

  // Set color
  $('.colorpicker').minicolors('value', '#2ed1c1');

  // Show
  $('.rw_widget_colour').removeClass('rw_hidden');

  // update table colour upon changes in the colour picker
  $(".colorpicker").on('change', function() {
    var newCol = $(this).parent().find('.minicolors-swatch-color').attr('style');
    var newColText = $('input.text.minicolors-input').val();
    $('.colourChosen').attr('style', newCol);
    $('.colourChosenText').text(newColText);
  });
});
```

```css
.rw_hidden {
  display: none;
}
td div {
  min-width: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  min-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
td {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-minicolors/2.2.6/jquery.minicolors.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-minicolors/2.2.6/jquery.minicolors.min.js"></script>

<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.css"> 
<script src="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.js"></script>
-->
<form class="aui">
  <label class="rw_widget_colour">
    <div class="rw_widget_swatch">jaoja</div>
    <input class="text colorpicker" type="text" name="rw_widget_colour" value="#ff0" />
  </label>
</form>

Show a swatch:

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      new colour:
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="colourChosen">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="colourChosenText"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Right yes, but I was wanting to show a rectangle within the TD along with the colour code.  So not have the whole td become the colour.  It is the idea of the swatch within the input that I want to replicate. So very close!

Comment: @Kieveli I updated my answer based on your comments, let me know if it requires further tweaking

Answer (score 0):

You could use [colorpicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/) - it's a jquery plugin.

The output looks something like this, but the default color is customisable. On click of the box, the user is able to change the color.

Code sample attached.

[image: colorpicker]

```js
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
 color: '#0000ff',
 onShow: function (colpkr) {
  $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
  return false;
 },
 onHide: function (colpkr) {
  $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
  return false;
 },
 onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
  $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rachelgallen.com/css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://www.rachelgallen.com/css/layout.css" />
    <title>ColorPicker - jQuery plugin</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/js/colorpicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/js/eye.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/js/utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/js/layout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="colorSelector">
  <div style="background-color:#ff00ff"></div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the box that appears on click is rather large in the code sample. i think this too is customisable - the size, range etc., the docs are fairly informative